# Добавить функционал клавиш Enter и Backspace в рабочий калькулятор

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, case

Как добавить возможность при нажатии клавиши `Enter` получать тоже самое что и после операции с `=`, а также добавить новый action и функционал для клавиши `Backspace` (она же `DEL` на калькуляторе, которая не работает)? Удаление должно работать посимвольно, удаляя также знак `.`. Собственно код:

```js
$(function() {
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log(char)
    switch(char)
    {
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
      case '.':
      case ',':
        if(char == ',') char = '.';
        digitAction(char);
        break;
      case '-':
      case '+':
      case '=':
      case '/':
      case '*':
      case 'C':
        doAction(char);
        break;
    }
  });
  // Main variables
  var $screen = $('.screen');
  var value = 0;
  var start = true;
  var action = 0;

  // Display '0' on load
  $screen.text('0');

  // Digits
  $('.digit').on('click', function() {
    var mytext = $(this).text();
    digitAction(mytext);
  });
  
  function digitAction(mytext)
  {
    var curtext = (start) ? '0' : $screen.text();
    start = false;
    if (mytext === '.') {
      if (curtext.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    } else {
      if (curtext === '0') {
        // Overwrite
        $screen.text(mytext);
      } else {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    }
  }

  // Maths operations
  function Maths_operations() {
    var num = parseFloat($screen.text());
    switch (action) {
      case 0:
        { // Nothing?
          value = num;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        { // Add
          value += num;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        { // Subtract
          value -= num;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        { // Multiply
          value *= num;
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        { // Divide
          if (num == 0) {
            value = 'Error'; // Couldn't divide by zero!
          } else {
            value /= num;
          }
        }
        break;
      case 5:
        { // Backspace
          // Some code here
        }
        break;
      default:
        break; // Shouldn't happen...
    }
    start = true; // New number now...
  }

  // Actions
  $('.action').on('click', function() {
    doAction($(this).text());
  });
  function doAction(op)
  {
    
    switch (op) {
      case 'C':
        {
          value = 0;
          $screen.text('0');
          action = 0;
          start = true;
        }
        break;  
      case 'DEL':
        { // Backspace
          Maths_operations();
          action = 5;
        }
        break;  
      case '\u00F7':
        { // Divide
          Maths_operations();
          action = 4;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00D7':
        { // Multiply
          Maths_operations();
          action = 3;
        }
        break;
      case '-':
        { // Subtract
          Maths_operations();
          action = 2;
        }
        break;
      case '+':
        { // Add
          Maths_operations();
          action = 1;
        }
        break;
      case '=':
        { // Equals
          Maths_operations();
          $screen.text(value);
          action = 0; // Nothing
        }
        break;
      default:
        { // If it's not a button
          console.log($(this).text());
        }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
/* Basic reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* Global text styling */
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Background */
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(171, 168, 168, 0.82);
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Name */
.pre-top > span {
  display: block;
  
  /* Special text styling */
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', Monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.pre-top .version {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Calculator body */
.calculator {
  
  /* Absolute horizontal & vertical centering */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 9px;
  background: #b8c6cc;
  background: linear-gradient(#979fa2 14.9%, #6a7073 52.31%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  
  /* Using box shadows to create 3D effects */
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5e6264, 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Top */
.top span.clear {
  float: left;
}

.top .screen {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* Inset shadow on the screen to create some indent */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Clear floats */
.keys,
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Applying same to the keys */
.keys span,
.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 11px 0;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
 
  /* Smoothing out hover and active states using css3 transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  /* Prevent selection of text inside keys in all browsers*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.keys span {
  width: 84px;
}

/* Style different type of keys (operators/evaluate/clear) differently */
.keys span.operator {
  background: #f5ac75;
  /* Remove right margins from operator keys */
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.keys span.eval {
  background: #79de9e;
  color: #fff;
}

.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  background: #e79199;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Some hover effects */
.keys span:hover {
  background: #7d8ae3;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5963a0;
  color: #fff;
}

.keys span.operator:hover {
  background: #fa9345;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #ce8248;
}

.keys span.eval:hover {
  background: #39f788;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #2fc66e;
  color: #fff;
}

.top span.clear:hover,
.top span.backspace:hover {
  background: #f86670;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #d5656d;
}

/* Simulating "pressed" effect on active state of the keys by removing the box-shadow and moving the keys down a bit */
.keys span:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #6b54d3;
}

.keys span.eval:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #717a33;
}

.top span.clear:active,
.top span.backspace:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #d3545d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Some Google Fonts -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab|Roboto+Mono:500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Calculator -->
<div class="calculator">

  <!-- Name -->
  <div class="pre-top">
    <span class="name">jQuery calculator</span>
    <span class="version">v1.1</span>
  <div>

  <!-- Clear key & screen-->
  <div class="top">
    <span class="action clear">C</span>
    <span class="action backspace">DEL</span>
    <span class="screen"></span>
  </div>

  <!-- Operators and other keys -->
  <div class="keys">
    <span class="digit">7</span>
    <span class="digit">8</span>
    <span class="digit">9</span>
    <span class="action operator">+</span>
    <span class="digit">4</span>
    <span class="digit">5</span>
    <span class="digit">6</span>
    <span class="action operator">-</span>
    <span class="digit">1</span>
    <span class="digit">2</span>
    <span class="digit">3</span>
    <span class="action operator">&divide;</span>
    <span class="digit">0</span>
    <span class="digit">.</span>
    <span class="action eval">=</span>
    <span class="action operator">&times;</span>
  </div>
    
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjqaQq) версия.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо!

Comment: обновили ответ, включили обработчик по delete и backspace

Comment: Не работает почему-то...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('keypress, keydown', function(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    var ekc = event.keyCode;
    console.log('char ' + char);
    console.log('ekc ' + ekc);
    switch (char) {
      case '-':
      case '+':
      case '=':
      case '/':
      case '*':
      case 'C':
        doAction(char);
        break;
    }

    switch (ekc) {
      case 48:
      case 96:
        digitAction('0');
        break;
      case 49:
      case 97:
        digitAction('1');
        break;
      case 50:
      case 98:
        digitAction('2');
        break;
      case 51:
      case 99:
        digitAction('3');
        break;
      case 52:
      case 100:
        digitAction('4');
        break;
      case 53:
      case 101:
        digitAction('5');
        break;
      case 54:
      case 102:
        digitAction('6');
        break;
      case 55:
      case 103:
        digitAction('7');
        break;
      case 56:
      case 104:
        digitAction('8');
        break;
      case 57:
      case 105:
        digitAction('9');
        break;
      case 110:
        //point
        digitAction('.');
        break;
      case 188:
        //comma
        digitAction('.');
        break;
      case 107:
        doAction('+');
        break;
      case 109:
      case 189:
        doAction('-');
        break;
      case 111:
        doAction('/');
        break;
      case 106:
        doAction('*');
        break;
      case 13:
        doAction('=');
        break;
      case 8:
        //Backspace
        doAction('DEL');
        break;
      case 46:
        //DELETE
        doAction('DEL');
        break;


    }

  });


  // Main variables
  var $screen = $('.screen');
  var value = 0;
  var start = true;
  var action = 0;

  // Display '0' on load
  $screen.text('0');

  // Digits
  $('.digit').on('click', function() {
    var mytext = $(this).text();
    digitAction(mytext);
  });

  function digitAction(mytext) {
    var curtext = (start) ? '0' : $screen.text();
    start = false;
    if (mytext === '.') {
      if (curtext.indexOf('.') < 0) {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    } else {
      if (curtext === '0') {
        // Overwrite
        $screen.text(mytext);
      } else {
        $screen.text(curtext + mytext);
      }
    }
  }

  // Maths operations
  function Maths_operations() {
    var num = parseFloat($screen.text());
    var text = $screen.text();
    console.log('num' + num);
    switch (action) {
      case 0:
        { // Nothing?
          value = num;
        }
        break;
      case 1:
        { // Add
          value += num;
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        { // Subtract
          value -= num;
        }
        break;
      case 3:
        { // Multiply
          value *= num;
        }
        break;
      case 4:
        { // Divide
          if (num == 0) {
            value = 'Error'; // Couldn't divide by zero!
          } else {
            value /= num;
          }
        }
        break;
      case 5:
        { // Backspace
          // Some code here
          var text = $screen.text();
          if ((text.length - 1) == 0) {
            $screen.html('0');
          } else {
            $screen.html(text.substring(0, text.length - 1));
          }
        }
        break;
      default:
        break; // Shouldn't happen...
    }
    start = true; // New number now...
  }

  // Actions
  $('.action').on('click', function() {
    doAction($(this).text());
  });

  function doAction(op) {
    console.log(op);
    switch (op) {
      case 'C':
        {
          value = 0;
          $screen.text('0');
          action = 0;
          start = true;
        }
        break;
      case 'DEL':
        { // Backspace
          Maths_operations();
          action = 5;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00F7':
        { // Divide
          Maths_operations();
          action = 4;
        }
        break;
      case '\u00D7':
        { // Multiply
          Maths_operations();
          action = 3;
        }
        break;
      case '-':
        { // Subtract
          Maths_operations();
          action = 2;
        }
        break;
      case '+':
        { // Add
          Maths_operations();
          action = 1;
        }
        break;
      case '=':
        { // Equals
          Maths_operations();
          $screen.text(value);
          action = 0; // Nothing
        }
        break;
      default:
        { // If it's not a button
          console.log($(this).text());
        }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
/* Basic reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Global text styling */
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* Background */

html {
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(171, 168, 168, 0.82);
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Name */

.pre-top > span {
  display: block;
  /* Special text styling */
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', Monospace, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
.pre-top .version {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
/* Calculator body */

.calculator {
  /* Absolute horizontal & vertical centering */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 9px;
  background: #b8c6cc;
  background: linear-gradient(#979fa2 14.9%, #6a7073 52.31%);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* Using box shadows to create 3D effects */
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5e6264, 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Top */

.top span.clear {
  float: left;
}
.top .screen {
  height: 40px;
  width: 212px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /* Inset shadow on the screen to create some indent */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* Typography */
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
/* Clear floats */

.keys,
.top {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Applying same to the keys */

.keys span,
.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 66px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 8px 11px 0;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Smoothing out hover and active states using css3 transitions */
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  /* Prevent selection of text inside keys in all browsers*/
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.keys span {
  width: 84px;
}
/* Style different type of keys (operators/evaluate/clear) differently */

.keys span.operator {
  background: #f5ac75;
  /* Remove right margins from operator keys */
  margin-right: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.keys span.eval {
  background: #79de9e;
  color: #fff;
}
.top span.clear,
.top span.backspace {
  background: #e79199;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Some hover effects */

.keys span:hover {
  background: #7d8ae3;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #5963a0;
  color: #fff;
}
.keys span.operator:hover {
  background: #fa9345;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #ce8248;
}
.keys span.eval:hover {
  background: #39f788;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #2fc66e;
  color: #fff;
}
.top span.clear:hover,
.top span.backspace:hover {
  background: #f86670;
  box-shadow: 0 4px #d5656d;
}
/* Simulating "pressed" effect on active state of the keys by removing the box-shadow and moving the keys down a bit */

.keys span:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #6b54d3;
}
.keys span.eval:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #717a33;
}
.top span.clear:active,
.top span.backspace:active {
  top: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 #d3545d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Calculator -->
<div class="calculator">

  <!-- Name -->
  <div class="pre-top">
    <span class="name">jQuery calculator</span>
    <span class="version">v1.1</span>
    <div>

      <!-- Clear key & screen-->
      <div class="top">
        <span class="action clear">C</span>
        <span class="action backspace">DEL</span>
        <span class="screen"></span>
      </div>

      <!-- Operators and other keys -->
      <div class="keys">
        <span class="digit">7</span>
        <span class="digit">8</span>
        <span class="digit">9</span>
        <span class="action operator">+</span>
        <span class="digit">4</span>
        <span class="digit">5</span>
        <span class="digit">6</span>
        <span class="action operator">-</span>
        <span class="digit">1</span>
        <span class="digit">2</span>
        <span class="digit">3</span>
        <span class="action operator">&divide;</span>
        <span class="digit">0</span>
        <span class="digit">.</span>
        <span class="action eval">=</span>
        <span class="action operator">&times;</span>
      </div>

    </div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ud83xpn/)

Comment: Почему то не работает и `.` `,` сломались.

Comment: Есть вариант использовать: `$screen.text(num.toString(10).slice(0, -1));` , но это тоже стирает нетривиально.

Comment: @kirbrown уточните, что именно не работает (код был проверен) ?

Comment: Вот версия от Вас http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avLjGV?editors=001 (надеюсь, я правильно вставил код). Не работает ввод `.` и `,` c клавиатуры, иногда `del` начинает работать со второго раза (только кнопка) и что самое интересное: например вводим число 77, нажимаем `del`, получаем 7 потом жмём `+`, видим 0 и получаем 84, a не 14. Очень хочется домучать этот калькулятор, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @kirbrown обновили ответ

Comment: Я подправил работу некоторых клавиш, например `.` Всё работает отлично, только не исчезла проблема с `del` - она так и срабатывает со второго раза только иногда, а также с числами после удаления, см. предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @kirbrown вы тестировали наш код? указанные проблемы были устранены, [тестовый пример](http://testwork.ru/stackoverflow/458464.html)

Comment: Да, однако всё работает как и прежде.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30347/discussion-between-alex-and-kirbrown).